# How to update from Drupal core 8.5.0 to 8.5.5?

Tags: 8, drush, updating, composer

In the past (Drupal 7), security-only update via drush was simple as:

```
drush up --security-only
```

now, Drush 9.3 returns:

> Command "up" is ambiguous.
>   Did you mean one of these?
>   ...

`composer` does not help either:

```
composer outdated drupal/*
```

returns *nothing*.

In fact, my Drupal is outdated:

[image]

How can I update Drupal security updates via command line?

UPDATE (`composer prohibits`):

```
$ composer prohibits drupal/core:8.5.5
There is no installed package depending on "drupal/core" in versions not matching 8.5.5
```

Answer (score 2):

It's all here [Update core via Composer](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer).

Short version, turn on maintenance mode

```
drush sset system.maintenance_mode 1
```

then run

```
composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
drush updatedb
drush cr
```

Turn off maintenance mode

```
drush sset system.maintenance_mode 0
```

> If you run the `composer update` command above but drupal/core is not
>   updated, there might be another dependency holding back the Drupal
>   upgrade. You can check for blocking dependencies using the command
>   `composer prohibits`. For example, if you are trying to upgrade from
>   8.4.5 to 8.5.0, you can run `composer prohibits drupal/core:8.5.0`, and it should give a list of dependencies blocking the upgrade. Update
>   those dependencies along with drupal/core and it should work (e.g.
>   `composer update drupal/core symfony/* --with-dependencies`).

Comment: If `composer outdated drupal/*` returns nothing, that won't do anything. I think it's likely the OP is running this in the web root, and not managing the site with Composer in the "proper" way. If that's true then their current project, the one at /composer.json, _is_ drupal/core (well drupal/drupal strictly speaking), so there's nothing to update

Comment: @Clive could you please point to _the "proper" way_?

Comment: Something along these lines @ohho: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies#download-core-option-a